# Passing Parameters into a Callback Function

Tags: javascript, callback

I have a function that listens for a click on the screen and fires a callback. It is part of a Helper object (which is why is preceded by the term Helper in my sample code. That is irrelevant however.

```
var Helper = { 
    bodyClickListener: function(fn) {
        var window = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        window.click();
        CORE.dom.on(window, 'click', function(event) {
            CORE.dom.off(window, 'click');
            fn(event);
        });
    }
}
```

I need to be able to pass a function into this function with a parameter that has been previously set.

```
function someFunction() {    
    var popup = document.getElementById('tagResultsPopup');
    Helper.bodyClickListener(function(popup) {
        return function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            removePopup(popup);
        };              
    }(document.getElementById('tagResultsPopup')));

    function removePopup(element) {
        if(element) {
            element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
        }
    };
}
```

The code above works, but you'll notice that I have to set the popup variable inside of the callback function. It has already been set above. How do I pass a  reference to the earlier variable into the callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to use closure in this way:

```
Helper.bodyClickListener(function(popup) {
    return function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        removePopup(popup);
    };              
}(document.getElementById('tagResultsPopup')));
```

That way the callback function has access to the variable I pass into the parameter function. So here, the return is actually the function I am passing as the callback.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you don't need to do much. You can just use the `popup` variable defined outside.

```
var popup = document.getElementById('tagResultsPopup');
Helper.bodyClickListener(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    //Don't set it  
    //var popup = document.getElementById('tagResultsPopup');
    removePopup(popup);//popup will refer to the correct variable
});
```

Comment: I wish this were true, but unfortunately it does not work. bodyClickListener does not reside in the same function as the popup variable. I just call the function and pass it a function.

Comment: @ryandlf that's not very clear from your question. Then why do you **not** what to just get the element again?

Comment: Sorry, I think i'm confusing you. Helper.bodyClickListener is in the same function as popup variable, but the actual function that Helper.bodyClickListener is calling is in the Helper object. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with why the variable isn't being passed or not.

Comment: @ryandlf I'm still not all that clear, can you change the code in your question to what it really is OR if its too long post it on jsfiddle or something? A small working example.

Comment: Edited. I hope that makes it a little clearer. As previously mentioned, I don't know if that is why the variable is not being called but I mentioned they weren't in the same function for clarification. When the callback gets passed to bodyClick, the popup variable is lost somehow. I can't figure out how to pass popup along with the callback function so it can be referenced.

Comment: ok that makes it a little better but, why **DON'T** you want to get `popup` right before you call `removePopup` ? Why do you want the variable outside the function?

Answer (score 0):

The function that you are passing to bodyClickListener is a closure. You can simply reference 'popup' inside that function without any problem. You don't have to create a new variable.